# Storing any number of different classes in one property

Tags: objective-c, class, properties

I have a collection of instances of different classes (9 to be precise), all with identical methods and properties, but each one performs a specific task.

I want to be able to switch between these different objects at any point. There maybe times when only a few of the objects get used, sometimes when they all get used, and other times when only one is used.

Ideally, I want a single property that could point to an instance of any of these objects. Ive tried doing something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id * currentObj;
...
currentObj=[[ClassType3 alloc] init];
```

(`ClassType3` is just one of the 9 different classes, in this example they go from `ClassType1` to `ClassType9`)

But that doesn't work, I get these two warnings:

```
Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type.
Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership.
```

My question is, can something like this be achieved, or do I need to create an instance of each class just in case it needs to be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`id` is already a pointer.

Change

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id * currentObj;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id currentObj;
```

Moreover, please use capitalized names for classes.

Comment: Doh! I didnt realize id was already a pointer. So many problems caused by a single asterisk. Many thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Gabriele gave already a correct answer. However,
if all the classes have identical methods and properties, you should consider to

- make all classes inherit from a common superclass, and declare the property as

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) SuperClass * currentObj;
  ```
- **OR** define a `@protocol` which comprises the common methods/properties, make all
  classes conform to that protocol, and declare the property as

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) id <YourProtocol> currentObj;
  ```

The advantage in both cases is that the compiler can do more/better error checking when
the property is assigned or used.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will be looking into these now.